# Incorrect output when implementing autocorrelation in C++

Tags: c++

Edit: SOLVED! I think my wav values were importing strangely but it now works perfectly

I am trying to implement autocorrelation on a pre-recorded signal in order to determine its frequency. I am using the brute-force definition as outlined in the Autocorrelation Wikipedia page under 'Efficient calculation'. The code will eventually be used as part of a real-time autotune device and so the input data is the amplitude values of someone singing. The data has a sample rate of 44100Hz.

It is my understanding that the final value calculated will be the maximum, that is the point at which every sample is multiplied by every other sample and added together. My output should look something like - i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Mm7.png

But instead looks like this (when I plot the data in Excel):

[My autocorrelation signal - 1800 samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG18W.png)

My code is shown below. It takes a file containing a certain number of samples ('values'), the user chooses a sample rate (how many samples to perform the autocorrelation on at any one time), and the autocorrelation is then performed up until the end of the input file is reached.

```
int i, j, k = 0; //Integers for loop counts 
unsigned int N; //Number of samples

int main()
{
    //Opens file
    FILE *amp;
    amp = fopen("Vocal1_Wav_Amplitude.txt", "r");

    //Returns error if file cannot be read
    if (amp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        getchar();
        exit(0);
    }

    //Count the number of lines in the file 
    int c;
    int values = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(amp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            values++;
    }

    //Creates array the size of the number of lines in the file for storing calculations
    float* autocor = new float[values]();

    //Imports values from file into array 
    float * array = new float[values];
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("Vocal1_Wav_Amplitude.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < values; i++) {
        inData >> array[i];
    }inData.close();

    //User enters sample rate
    cout << "Enter sample rate (number of samples for each calculation) : ";
    cin >> N;
    int measurements = values / N; //number of times to repeat the autocorrelation on the signal

//Performs autocorrelation on the input data 
for (k = 0; k < measurements; ++k) {
    for (size_t i = k * N; i < ((k + 1)*(N - 1)) + k; ++i) {
        autocor[i] = 0;
        for (size_t j = k * N; j <= i; ++j) {
            const size_t idxA = j
                , idxR = ((k + 1)*N) - (i - j) - 1;
            autocor[i] += array[idxA] * array[idxR];
        }
    }
}

//Saves autocorrelation calculations to a new file
FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        getchar();
        exit(0);
    }
        for (i = 0; i < values; ++i) {
            fprintf(fp, "%f\n", autocor[i]);
        }

    printf ("Press enter to close...");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I believe my main issue is with this piece of code:

```
for (k = 0; k < measurements; ++k) {
    for (size_t i = k * N; i < ((k + 1)*(N - 1)) + k; ++i) {
        autocor[i] = 0;
        for (size_t j = k * N; j <= i; ++j) {
                  const size_t idxA = j
                             , idxR = ((k + 1)*N) - (i - j) - 1;
            autocor[i] += array[idxA] * array[idxR];
        }
    }
}
```

It should take the signal and multiply it with its inverse as each sample is shifted along, and then add all the individual multiplications together. However if this was the case then I should get the max peak for the final value. Can anyone seen any problems with this code? I've asked on here 2 times before to get it working and it seemed to be perfect until I actually went to plot the data or try and determine the frequency from it.

Comment: I think my problem is to with my amplitude data that I'm using as an input. It should give values between -1 and 1 right? However it's giving values from 0 to -9

Comment: Perhaps I need to normalise the amplitude values of the .wav file somehow?

Comment: Could you please send the fixed code as answer? I just invested some effort - cleaned up the C++ code but get stuck in the actual algorithm. Autocorrelation is new to me and I didn't find enough time to manage it fully.